# is the anyway to use $.inArray (or alternative) with a javascript array of objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, collections

I have the following array in javascript:

```
var myFirstArray = [1,2,3];
```

and i use $.inArrray() to see if a specific number is in that array like this

```
 var num =3;
 var exists = $.inArray(num, myFirstArray) > -1;
```

I now have an array of objects

```
var myArray = [{value:1, label:"bird"}, {value:2, label:"dog"}, {value:3, label: "cat"}];
```

if there anyway to use $.inArray() to search within a field of an object?  Something like this:

```
var num = 3;
var exists = $.inArray(num, myFirstArray, (r) {return r.value}) > -1;
```

if the answer is NO, is there an alternative function that would give me this behavior that is performant?

Comment: No. See the documentation: [`inArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) does not allow a  predicate function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively you can use one of the jQuery methods [grep](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) or [each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).

```
var num = 3;
var myArray = [{value: 1, label: "bird"}, {value:2, label:"dog"}, {value:3, label: "cat"}];

var result = jQuery.grep(myArray, function( element, index ) {
    return ( num === element.value );
});

var found = false;
$.each(myArray, function ( index, element ) {
    if ( num === element.value ) {
        found = true;
        return false;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the native [Array#some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method:

```
var num =3;
var myArray = [{value:1, label:"bird"}, {value:2, label:"dog"}, {value:3, label: "cat"}];

var exists = myArray.some(function(o) {
    return o.value === num;
});
```

[**Live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/D9NWQ/1/)

If you need support for pesky IE<9: [MDN Array.prototype.some shim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some#Compatibility) or you may also use a complete [ES5 shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim) already (thanks @user2864740). Underscore also provides the [`_.some`](http://underscorejs.org/#some) utility.

Comment: @user2864740 Thanks, added the link to the answer. `=]`